# Get the same Java Class instance I'm passing through parameter

Tags: java, class, parameters

I'm developing a web-app in **Java** language, which is composed by a system and some modules. All of them implement the `IAppIdentifier` interface and I have all the module references and the system itself stored in a `List` into the system.

The idea is to design that in such way that every module will be able to access the system itself or another modules if they have the required interface (extended from IAppIdentifier), so they have to ask the system for them.

I have this code which works:

```
@Override
public IAppIdentifier moduleByClass(Class<? extends IAppIdentifier> clazz) {
    List<IAppIdentifier> iApps = this.get_Iapps();
    for (IAppIdentifier iApp : iApps) {
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(iApp.getClass())) {
            return iApp;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Basically it's checking that each class from the array is assignable from the required interface and if it is it will return that instance. However the matter is that I have to cast it when it's returned by the method.

For example I have to implement something like that to obtain system's instance:

```
((ISystem) this.get_Service().moduleByClass(ISystem.class))
```

My question is, is there any way in java to avoid doing that casting again, ergo, to ensure it will return the same type I'm passing as argument at compile time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change method signature to this one :

```
public <T extends IAppIdenfitier> T moduleByClass(Class<T> clazz)
```

This should work.

Even if your `interface` isn't generic you can still use generics in methods for they own purpose. By this code you provide generic rule that `T` has to be `IAppIdentifier` itself or has to extend it. Your method now will return object of type `T` and take as param class as `Class<T>`.

Then in your code whenever you invoke method `moduleByClass` you don't have to cast it, for example:

```
ISystem = this.get_Service().moduleByClass(ISystem.class);
```

Cast won't be needed here and everything will compile.

There is more info needed according to @XtremeBiker good comment. Inside `moduleByClass` method it's needed to cast resulting type to `T`. So it was:

```
return iApp;
```

But now it should be:

```
return clazz.cast(iApp);
```

Anyway it's still less annoying to make cast in on place inside method body than doing it everytime when that method is invoke.

Comment: That works like a charm, even an unchecked cast is needed `return (T) iApp;` That's what Eclipse says at least.

Comment: Yes, inside `moduleByClass` you have to cast `iApp` variable as you wrote.